# Calculate difference between values using a filter using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that for each row contains information about an event and if the event was successful or not. I want to calculate the delta between non-succesfull events, I know how to the calculate the diff between fields but not when using a filter.

My dataframe has this structure:

```
      Timestamp     Status          
   0 2012-01-01     OK 
   1 2012-01-02     OK 
   2 2012-01-03     FAIL
   3 2012-01-05     OK 
   4 2012-01-06     OK 
   5 2012-01-07     FAIL
```

What I want is to calculate the time for each row until the next fail, so somtethin like this:

```
      Timestamp     Status     Days_until_next_fail              
   0 2012-01-01     OK         2
   1 2012-01-02     OK         1
   2 2012-01-03     FAIL       0
   3 2012-01-05     OK         2
   4 2012-01-06     OK         1
   5 2012-01-07     FAIL       0
```

I tried this:

```
df['days_until_next_failure'] = df.Timestamp - df[(df.Status == '1')].Timestamp(+1)
```

But that returns NaT and I can't find anything in the documentation to apply filtering and use shift. One option is to iterate over the dataframe beginning at the end but that seems a bit inefficient.

Comment: this is a job for `cumsum`...though it will take a few lines of code to get what you want. ( `cumsum` will tell you how many 1s there are up to a certain point in the data.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives the days since last fail, rather than days until next:

```
is_fail = (df.Status != 'OK')
cumulative_fails = is_fail.cumsum()
fail_idx, = is_fail.nonzero()
days_since_last_fail = arange(len(is_fail))
days_since_last_fail[fail_idx[0]:] -= fail_idx[cumulative_fails[fail_idx[0]:]-1]
```

If you want the correct version, then you can adapt this for yourself, or possibly just invert the original array at the start and end.

Comment: yeah, I'm going to actually try it in python and fix it.

Comment: @jezrael - I copy pasted  to quickly, try it now

Comment: It return `[0 1 0 1 2 0]`

Comment: Super, I think you get it.

Comment: Great works perfectly. I reversed the dataframe in order to get the days ahead and that works perfectly. Do you maybe also have a suggestion when some days don't have rows, or sometimes on one day two timestamps?

Comment: @Chrisp - I thought you might have wanted something like that.  You can use this general method, but with an extra step or two.  Basically, rather than using `arange` as a reliable indicator of day, you need to use it to index into the list of days to get the true day.  And then do something similar when you do the subtraction on the last line...hopefully that's enough to figure it out?!

Answer (score 1):

Solution if column `Timestamp` is sorted and contains all days in every month:

You can try first find groups of data by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by this `Serie` and aggregate [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html). You get `NaN`, so [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by `0` and convert output column to integer by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
#reverse ordering
df = df[::-1]

print (df.Status == 'FAIL').astype(int).cumsum()
5    1
4    1
3    1
2    2
1    2
0    2
Name: Status, dtype: int32

#filter and get ordering of colums
df['Days_until_next_fail'] = df[df.Status=='OK']
                              .groupby((df.Status == 'FAIL').astype(int).cumsum())
                              .cumcount() + 1

#replace NaN by 0, convert values to integer                              
df['Days_until_next_fail'] = df['Days_until_next_fail'].fillna(0).astype(int)
#ordering to original
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print df
   Timestamp Status  Days_until_next_fail
0 2012-01-01     OK                     2
1 2012-01-02     OK                     1
2 2012-01-03   FAIL                     0
3 2012-01-05     OK                     2
4 2012-01-06     OK                     1
5 2012-01-07   FAIL                     0
```

More general solution, (all dates have to be sorted):

```
print df
   Timestamp Status
0 2011-12-28     OK
1 2012-01-02     OK
2 2012-01-03   FAIL
3 2012-01-05     OK
4 2012-01-06     OK
5 2012-01-07   FAIL

#reverse ordering
df = df[::-1]

df['days_until_next_failure'] = df.groupby((df.Status == 'FAIL').astype(int).cumsum())
                                  .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0][0] - x.Timestamp)
                                  .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

print df.sort_index()
   Timestamp Status  days_until_next_failure
0 2011-12-28     OK                   6 days
1 2012-01-02     OK                   1 days
2 2012-01-03   FAIL                   0 days
3 2012-01-05     OK                   2 days
4 2012-01-06     OK                   1 days
5 2012-01-07   FAIL                   0 days
```

If you need convert column from `timedelta` to `int`:

```
df['fail_days'] = df.groupby((df.Status == 'FAIL').astype(int).cumsum())
                    .apply(lambda x: ((x.iloc[0][0] - x.Timestamp) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D'))
                                        .astype(int))

                    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

print df.sort_index()
   Timestamp Status  fail_days
0 2011-12-28     OK          6
1 2012-01-02     OK          1
2 2012-01-03   FAIL          0
3 2012-01-05     OK          2
4 2012-01-06     OK          1
5 2012-01-07   FAIL          0
```

Comment: you can do it without `groupby`, simply by indexing into df['Timestamp'] using the output of the "global" `cumsum`

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand.

Comment: in that case I shall have to provide my own answer! (partly my fault for not explaining well I guess)

Comment: @Chris p - Is possible 2 consecutive `FAIL` values?

Comment: Yeah that's possible. Because I need both solutions: number of fails and time between fails both solutions are working perfectly. I Implemented the above code and it works perfectly. Too bad I cannot accept two answers

Comment: Yes, you are right. Maybe my answer in your next question  can be accepted. ;) Nice day and good luck. Btw, always upvote any StackOverflow answer if is helpful (not only my answer, I think any answer).